# Is $\ln(x^{p(x)}) = p(x) \ln(x)$?

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to prove that:

$x^{\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}} = \ln(x)$

My "solution":

$e^{\ln\left(x^{\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}}\right)} = e^{\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)} \ln(x)} = e^{\ln(\ln(x))} = \ln(x)$

Is the first step valid, i.e is $\ln(x^{p(x)}) = p(x) \ln(x)$

How can I find out for myself?

Comment: well $\ln$ has this property.. you can exponentiate both sides for instance

Comment: Note that we need $x>1$ else $\ln \ln x$ is undefined.

Comment: Yes your step is valid.

Comment: Also, while your solution works, you don't need to go through the exponential; you can simply take logarithms of both sides, since $\ln(a)=\ln(b)\implies a=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}}$$
$$=x^{\log_x(\ln(x))}$$
$$=\ln(x)^{\log_x(x)}$$
$$=\ln(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $\displaystyle x^{\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\ln x}}\;,$ Now Let $\ln x= y\Rightarrow x=e^y$

So expression convert into $\displaystyle e^{\frac{y\ln y}{y}} = e^{\ln y} = y = \ln x$

Note that $\ln(x)^{p(x)} = p(x)\cdot \ln x\;,$ Where $x>0$

Answer (score 1):

Answering *the question*. For $a>0$ we have by definition of logarithm that 
$$
a^b=e^{\ln(a^b)}.
$$
and on the other hand
$$
a^b=(e^{\ln a})^b=e^{b\ln a}
$$
Comparing two expressions and noting that the exponential function is injective we get
$$
\ln(a^b)=b\ln a.
$$
Now apply it to $a=x$ and $b=p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ = $ln(x)$
So $x^{ln(y)/y}$ = $y$
Take ln both sides and simplify using the property: $ln(x^{ln(y)}/y)$ = $ln(y);ln(x)/y$.
so $ln(y)ln(x)/y$ = $ln(y)$
We get  $ln(y)y/y$ = $ln(y)$

Comment: $\LaTeX$, please...

Comment: @user190080 What is that?

Comment: please check [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), basically it makes your post much easier to read, for example x^ln(y) becomes $x^{\ln(y)}$